# Postgresql : What is the maximum number of stored procedures can be written for the postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Need to know the Best practice to write the stored procedures for the database. So what is the maximum number of stored procedures can be written for postgresql database for readability and maintainability. Also please let me know if there is any standards for writing stored procedures.

Comment: There is no practical limit. Why do you need to know?

Comment: There is no limit that I am aware of. There are extensions, e.g. PostGIS, that come with over 1k stored procedures. Why are you concerned?

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name : Actually I have many stored procedure i.e. more than 40. So I need to think if there is any limit on writing stored procedures for code maintainability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit (within reason).  The key for maintainability is to separate stored procedures into logical functional areas (business units) using schemas and naming conventions.  For example, in a over-simplified business database you could create three schemas: finance, customers, inventory.  Then organize your stored procedures into those schemas.  For example:

- finance.calculate_year_end_report
- finance.update_finance_record
- customer.create_customer
- inventory.update_current_inventory

You can create smaller organization sets under these using naming conventions.  For example you could do this inside finance:

- finance.**tax**_calculate_estimated_taxes
- finance.**tax**_aggregate_sales_tax
- finance.**report**_calculate_year_end
- finance.**report**_ytd_revenue
- finance.update_finance_record

Comment: Thank you. So you mean there is no limit for stored procedures even for individual schema.